# how to install oracle instant client for xampp

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I have XAMPP for Windows 1.7.3 installed.

I'm using Zend Framework and need to use the pdo_oci8 extension. I've enabled the extension - but now getting the error that it can't find the oci.dll file.

I've downloaded the instantclient_11_2 zip file from oracle. Unzipped it. It contains a bunch of dll files.

How do I install this on windows? Do I need to run a cmd prompt or move it to a specific folder under xampp?

Comment: Any reason why you're using XAMPP and not Zend Server CE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I unzipped the file into a directory.

That directory I placed in c:\xampp, e.g. c:\xampp\intanstclient_11_2

Then I added that to my windows path variable.

Quite simple really in the end.

Answer (score 6):

Below you will find the instructions on how to configure/install and enable the Oracle Instant Client for XAMPP v7, v5.5 and v5.6.

1. Download and install XAMPP
2. Modify the php.ini in "C:\xampp\php"

   - Uncomment the following line ";extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client"
   - Restart Apache
3. Download the 32 bit (PHP is 32 bit so no need to 64) Oracle Instant Client

   - You need both Instant Client Package - Basic and Instant Client Package - SDK
   - Unzip both in "C:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1" and "c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk" respectivly
4. Add the directory "C:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1" to the windows path veritable

   - Under system Properties click Environment Variables
   - Edit the Path variable
   - You need to reboot windows
5. (Optional) If you want to specify the oracle connections in the tnsnames.ora file:

   - Create a file called "tnsnames.ora" in "C:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1"
   - Add your oracle connections to the file as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/tnsnames.htm#NETRF007
   - Create a new environmental variable called "TNS_ADMIN" with the value of "C:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1"
   - Reboot Windows

Thats it :)

instruction where taken from here: http://www.gi-architects.co.uk/2016/11/how-to-install-oracle-instant-client-v12-for-xampp-v7-v5-5-v5-6-windows/

Answer (score 4):

Google gave me this topic when I searched the problem, but I have not found solution here.

But I found here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-084410.html

My problem was that I downloaded the 64 version of Oracle instant client, and php seems to be working only with the 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved when I added path variable like "c:\instantclient_12_2" .